# How do I delete a solution from TFS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

how do I delete a Team project from TFS?. I am using VS2012.

The situation is that a Team Project was created with the wrong name, and another one was created with the right name and all the code has been checked into that.

I just want to delete the wrongly created one.  I cant find any specific help on this, although there are articles on how to do it on if your TFS is hosted on visualstudio.com.

Apologies if this is a noddy question but I have looked for the answer and cant find it...

Thanks in advance
Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "[TFSDeleteProject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181482.aspx)" command line tool to delete the team project.

Here is the usage:

```
TFSDeleteproject [/q] [/force] [/excludewss] /collection:URL TeamProjectName
```

TFSDeleteProject permanently destroys the team project, after which it cannot be recovered. You should backup all important project data before using TFSDeleteProject.

Required permissions
To use the TFSDeleteProject command, you must be a member of the Team Foundation Administrators security group or the Project Administrators security group.

You can use the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff357756.aspx) to delete the team project using the administrator console.

Comment: Thanks.  I am not an admin so I have passed this on to someone who is, but they arent around now.  Apologies for the delay acknowledging your answer.